# module 'sklearn.covariance' has no attribute 'GraphicalLassoCV'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run the script found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_stock_market.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-applications-plot-stock-market-py) for visualizing stock market clustering. However, I get this error:

```
File "/Users/jovan/Downloads/plot_stock_market.py", line 169, in <module>
    edge_model = covariance.GraphicalLassoCV(cv=5)

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.covariance' has no attribute 'GraphicalLassoCV'
```

Was `GraphicalLassoCV` deprecated or replaced with something else? I am using Python 3.7. Does anyone know how to make it work or what to replace it with?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Which version of sklearn are you using?

Answer (score 3):

YES, `GraphLassoCV` has been renamed to `GraphicalLassoCV` in the latest versions of `scikit-learn`. I guess you have an older version of `scikit-learn` and you are trying to run this code (which is meant for latest version and is incompatible with older versions).

Try running the code with `GraphLassoCV`.

---

**Replace this:**

```
edge_model = covariance.GraphicalLassoCV(cv=5)
```

**with this:**

```
edge_model = covariance.GraphLassoCV(cv=5)
```

---

**Output using `0.19.1` version of `scikit-learn`:**

[image]

Comment: Its the opposite. Previously GraphLassoCV was present which was renamed to GraphicalLassoCV in the latest version. See [changelog here](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html#sklearn-covariance) The OP seems to have an older version of scikit-learn and trying to run the newest examples. Hence the error.

Comment: This worked for me:

edge_model = covariance.GraphicalLassoCV()

Comment: then you have an old scikit-learn version. I would not do that. Update to the latest